# How to reduce number of calls to a helper method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, optimization, rails-activerecord

In my view, I need a User object to display a few different properties. There is an instance variable @comments that's being sent from the controller. I loop through the comments and get the User information through a helper method in order to reduce db calls.

Here is the helper method:

```
  def user(id)
    if @user.blank? == false && id == @user.id
      return @user
    else
      return @user = User.find(id)
    end
  end
```

And in the view, I display the details as follows:

```
<h4> <%=user(comment.user_id).name%> </h4> 
<p><%=user(comment.user_id).bio%></p> 
<p><%=user(comment.user_id).long_bio%></p> 
<p><%=user(comment.user_id).email%></p> 
<hr>
<p><%=user(comment.admin_id).bio%></p> 
<p><%=user(comment.admin_id).long_bio%></p> 
<p><%=user(comment.admin_id).email%></p>
```

I was told that assigning a variable in the view is bad practice and hence I am calling the helper method multiple times instead of assigning the returned User object.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you don't have a has_many and a belongs_to association set up so you could call user.comments or comment.user? Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Evo_x Sorry, I didn't realize that that i passed one `user_id`. There are actually two ids of the same User table as `user_id` and `admin_id`. I have updated above question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are overcomplicating things here.

Let's say you have a user model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :comments
end
```

an admin model

```
class Admin < User

end
```

a comment model

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
end
```

Now you only need a type column in your users table and you can do things like this:

```
Admin.all (All users with type "Admin")
User.all (Really all users including type "Admin" and all other types)
```

and for every comment you can just use

```
comment.user.bio
```

and it doesn't matter if it's an admin or not.

See http://www.therailworld.com/posts/18-Single-Table-Inheritance-with-Rails for example

Additional info: To reduce db calls in general(N+1 queries) watch http://railscasts.com/episodes/372-bullet

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly fine to pass models to your view and build the data on the view off of the data contained in the model. Keep in mind that I'm not entirely certain how you want your page to work, but one option you may have is to use a partial view and pass it the user object. This allows you to still only have the one model in your partial view without setting additional variables.

Also, without knowing what kind of database you're using or if your models have any associations, and assuming that you're doing some input validation, you may not need this helper method and may be able to lean on your ORM to get the user object.

For Example:

```
<%= comment.user.age %>
```

This isn't any more efficient than what you've currently got, but it certainly makes the code look cleaner.

Another alternative: set a user variable in the view. You're not performing logic in your view at this point, you're simply storing some data to the heap for later use.

Comment: hey @erahm, appreciate your answer although I have updated the question above. There are two ids of the same user table. Please also refer to the comment left below question. Thanks again.

Comment: No worries. In that case, you may be better off using your helper method than relying on the ORM, though you could still do something like comment.admin.id if you have the relationships built. You can render the same partial view multiple times though and could just pass the user model the first time, then render it again using the admin's user model. Assuming of course that you want the same data shown in the same fashion for both models.